# How to stop a infinite while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am writing this simple game for an assignment in my class. I am trying to make it so that once the user enters “yes”, it stops asking them if they would like to proceed to the Kanto region. But if they enter no, it loops them back to the beginning telling them that they are first proceeding to the Kanto region.

Edit: How would I make it so that if the users enters yes, it stops the loop and if he enters no, it continues the loop?

```
while gender=='boy' or gender=='Boy':
        #REGION KANTO
        print("We will first proceed to the Kanto Region.")
        print("You are currently facing the Kanto Region Pokemon Master, John!")
        #ATTACK
        attack=input("Would you like to use cut and hurt his Pokemon?")
        if attack=='yes' or attack=='Yes':
                print(starterP,"used cut! Foe Pokemon has fainted!")
                print("You will advance to the next region!")
                print("=====================================================")
        if attack=='no' or attack=='No':
                print(starterP,"got attacked!",starterP,"has fainted!")
                print("Game over!")
                print("=====================================================")
```

Comment: `break` will break it, but what's your *real* question?

Comment: use a `break` statement

Comment: You can't break out of _infinite_ loops

Answer (score 0):

Use `break` to exit from a while loop:

```
>>> while True:
...     x+=1
...     if x == 100:
...             print x
...             break
... 
100
>>>
```

However, your question is kind of unclear. Please leave a comment if my question is unsatisfactory.